# Import large number of records in laravel, each record having multiple relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a case where user uploads a file containing large number of rows(let's say 1000). Each row contain information about a user.

This data is turned into PHP array with objects
E.g

```
$userArray = [{first_name: 'Peter', last_name:'Pan', email 'peter@example.org'},
  {first_name: 'David', last_name:'Hasslehof', email 'david@example.org'}...]
```

Now for each row I would have to create

```
foreach ($usersArray as $user) {
    $createdUser = User::create(array('email' => $user['email'], 'pin' => $user['id_code']));
    $profile = Userprofile::create(array('first_name' => $user['first_name'], 'last_name' =>$user['last_name']));
    $createdUser->profile()->associate($profile);
    $createdUser->save();
    $usergroup->addMember($createdUser);
}
```

This would mean that if I had 1000 rows, atleast 4000 queries, which is obviously too much. Is there a eloquent way to do this more elegantly?

I tried using querybuilder and insert first all profiles and then users but this did not work, because I dont know which profiles to retrieve(first_name and last_name are not unique fields) and therefore cannot link profile_id's to users that I would like to create.

Comment: I think there is no other way then iterating and associating profiles to users. If this takes a lot of time consider using queues, which will do this tasks in the background. As for the unique keys you can generate one by your self. concat the upload batch number user id and some other unique id and hash. But eloquent already has a unique id field you can get it after saving the profile model.

Comment: I think you mean "is there a way to do this more Eloquently". ;)

Comment: More seriously though - if you're concerned about performance issues then the Eloquent ORM may need to be avoided in this case. I did an application in 4.2 that required transferring a large amount of data from an old schema to a new one, the speed difference between PDO (or python) and Eloquent was astounding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [this laravel library](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/tree/1.3) for import.

However, to import multiple relationships, i think there is no other way than use associate() or sync().

```
            $model_object =  new YourModelHere();

            //your model id here
            $model_object->id = $sheet->id;
            //your model id fields
            $model_object->field_1 = (int)$sheet->field_1;
            $model_object->field_2 = (int)$sheet->field_2;
            //related id of models heres
            $id_of_related_1 = (int) $sheet->id_of_related_1 ;
            $id_of_related_2  =  (int) $sheet->id_of_related_2;

            //in your Model.php the relation i.e. hasMany or Belongs to must be declared first.
            $model_object->relationToModelOne()->associate(RelatedModelOne::find($id_of_related_));

            $model_object->relationToModelTwo()->associate(RelatedModelTwo::find($id_of_related_2));


            $model_object->save();
```